# How to ask for help for seemingly random/unreproducible execution error?

Tags: discussion

I have recently experienced the pain of having an error happening once in a while and could not find any way to reproduce (purposely) that error.

As SO good practices suggest, a good question will be asked with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. But what if we can't provide that? I guess what we should do is provide as much information as possible and hope that someone will find a way to reproduce the error. But I don't think a question with no other information than "I am doing that, and it's not working...sometimes..." would get a lot of attention.

Note: for my case in particular, someone had the same problem as me on SO but his question was not answered. I didn't want to duplicate the question, but editing his post was not any better because I could not add any other information than "I have the same problem" ...

What should we do in that case? Is it still ok to ask that kind of question? Is there a good way to proceed?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/67122/how-do-i-approach-fixing-an-unreproducible-randomly-occurring-bug may be helpful.

Comment: this reminds me of a time when I had an app that crashed randomly about once a week. it mostly happened in production and no backtrace were available. after two days of research (i tried to find out on which occasions a crash is most likely) i finally found the "threadbleed" bug (i made up the term, don't try to search for it). openssl just is not threadsafe by default. sqlcipher + openssl on iOS = crash, in the default configuration. instead of fixing it, the openssl guys just say in the docs somewhere that you have to implement your own rw-mutex-hooks to make it threadsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way seems to be to post an answer on the other question asking if they have fixed it yet because you need the answer...

**But seriously,**

if you have the error, then you should have some idea of what parts of your code *could* be causing the issue. So I would suggest...

**if you think this may be a problem others will or have run into,**

posting the error, those parts which *may* give the error, and you could even link to the other question (at least showing that you have researched the issue). However, not *all* questions need code though most do. So if you could give enough explanation of what is happening in the app (without it being too extensive) then people may be able to help you decide which parts *could* be relevant.

**If you really can't narrow down any code that *may* cause the error**

Keep on searching and debugging until you have a little more to post with the question that may help others find your problem.

Just be aware that it may be closed as cannot be reproduced

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that and see if it gets any attention.